# How to Run a subversion post-commit hook as low-priority separate thread

Tags: svn, post-commit, svn-hooks

I have a long-running post-commit hook that updates an index of subversion repository (from the project http://svnquery.tigris.org/)  The postcommit hook already runs as a separate thread due to the RunDetached executable provided as part of svnquery. The postcommit hook is

```
C:\SvnIndex\RunDetached C:\SvnIndex\svnindex.exe update D:\IndexData D:\repository -f "(/tags/)|(/branches/)"
```

This works ok, except that it shoots the CPU usage up to 100% and starves out the other threads on the system, making my machine unresponsive.  Is there anyway in general to run a process with a lower thread priority from an svn hook?

(This is on a Windows Server 2003 box)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to RunDetached a batch file that runs svnindex and then uses something like [ProcessUtil](http://www.beyondlogic.org/consulting/processutil/processutil.htm) to lower its priority.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you file an enhancement request for the svnindex project:

> Add a new parameter to specify the
>   thread priority

Once that's implemented, you could then pass the new parameter in your hook script to svnindex.exe and have it run with the specified thread priority.

Comment: The enhancement has been implemented ;-) Use RunDetached from SvnQuery 1.1.2.0

Comment: Great! Thanks for implementing this.